# how to passdata between storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait{
        let secondView: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let main = secondView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        main.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(main, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape{

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

I use this code to switch between two different storyboard's viewcontroller. How can I pass data between those viewcontroller in two different storyboard.
I have tried "main.instanceData = myData before the present" It seems could work, but the initial value of myData is nil, so when this line of code was executed, it would show "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean in this case?  (Please show actual code of it not working.)

Comment: Why do you need to pass data between storyboards? Storyboard is just a group of View controller. Data should be passed back and forth for View controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. You can pass data to viewController directively like that:

```
let secondView: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let main = secondView.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
main.data = yourdata
main.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(main, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn’t work. I think it is because my viewcontrollers are in two different storyboards.

Comment: I think it not related to different storyboards. If you use Segue you cannot pass data between two storyboards.

Comment: I have tried your method again, it seems could work, but my data initial value is nil. So when this line of code was executed, it would show "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"